# FFMPEG: Series of .JPG images to H265 Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image-editing, aspect-ratio

I have a series of images I want to convert into a video. The images are formatted as follows:

```
Dimensions: 3840 x 2160
Width: 3840 pixels
Height: 2160 pixels
Horizontal Resolution: 30 dpi
Vertical Resolution: 72 dpi
Bit Depth: 24
```

`ffmpeg -framerate 23.976000 -i woa%04d.jpg -i original-audio.wav -c:v libx265 -crf 15 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv444p -c:a copy Output.mkv`

The issue I'm having is the JPG files are rendered into a square, ruining the original aspect ratio.

I've also tried the following:

`ffmpeg -framerate 23.976000 -i woa%04d.jpg -i original-audio.wav -c:v libx265 -crf 15 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv444p  -vf scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a copy Output.mkv`

Anyone have any suggestions?

This is the output of `ffmpeg -i  woa%04d.jpg`

This is what I get:

````
ffmpeg version N-94357-g4373bb411c Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.102 / 58. 28.102
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.101 /  7. 56.101
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, image2, from 'woa%04d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:03:43.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3840x2160 [SAR 30:72 DAR 20:27], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
At least one output file must be specified```
````

Comment: Share the full log of `ffmpeg -i woa%04d.jpg`

Comment: I added the output to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg sees the input as having a display ratio of 20:27. If that's undesired, you can reset the aspect ratio to 1.

`ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 -i woa%04d.jpg -i original-audio.wav -vf setsar=1 -c:v libx265 -crf 15 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv444p -c:a copy Output.mkv`

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick :) Thank you!

Comment: I got an error "Unknown parameter crf"